# Kernel Driver Problems

Tags: ethernet, ubuntu, kernel

### Background

I have a KVM that works with a custom Gaming PC, the last generation of Intel 16-inch MacBook Pro, a Pi4 B 8GB and an empty port for whatever I can think of next.  The wireless in my house absolutely stinks so we've converted nearly everything to Wired Ethernet using switches.

### Issue

I used the Pi's built-in GB Ethernet port until I burned up 1 of 2 the ethernet cables that took me forever to fish through walls etc.  In an effort to save my second wall port/cable I forced link Negotiation down to 100MB using the [Trendnet TU2-ET100](https://www.trendnet.com/products/product-detail?prod=290_TU2-ET100), because the chipset is natively supported by the [AX88772 kernel driver](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man4/axe.4freebsd.html).  I'm referring to the Ubuntu manpage because up until the new version(23.10), which I did a `do-dist-upgrade` for yesterday.  After upgrading, the driver will not properly load.  I'm not in front of my Pi right now, but `dmsg` reports something like `failed to write error -110`.  I used PENS to downgrade to 22.04D and the issue still exists.

What happened between 22.04 and 22.04D, AKA 22.04D and 23.10 kernel-wise besides a version upgrade, and does anyone know how to fix it?  I use Gentoo on a regular basis, so if I need to recompile a kernel I can.  I've just never done it in a Debian based environment.  Until I can fix this, I switched to Arch.

Comment: `the Pi's built-in 5GB ethernet port` - the what now? Are you suggesting the raspberry Pi's ethernet port caused damage to an ethernet cable? This is a wind up, right?

Comment: No I'm suggesting I might've bought cheap cable that's buried behind a wall.  In case it is cheap, I don't want to burn up the second cable, so I downgraded the speed to 10/100 by using the USB Ethernet Adapter.  My 5GB port is fine.  My wiring is suspect.  That said, I'd like to continue using Ubuntu on my Pi, but can't due to what I described in the question.  Sorry if I confused anyone.

Comment: OK, perhaps try a different USB ethernet device then - or try limiting the speed of the on board ONE gigabit (that's a **`1`** not a **`5`**) "built-in" ethernet port on the pi - still no idea why you think your raspberry pi 4 has built in 5 gigabit, and how you think that is at all relevant to the burning of a cable!!